# RangeError: index out of range when connect to cassandra databse in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I'm working on NodeJS project and I've tried to select data from table stored in cassandra database using cassandra-driver package,
I start the client connection using this line:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['192.168.0.253'], keyspace: 'test' });
```

sometimes when I call the url, the engine fetchs the result successfully, by the way sometimes raises this error:

```
{ [RangeError: index out of range]
  coordinator: '192.168.0.253:9042',
  query: 'SELECT * FROM table where hidden=false ALLOW FILTERING' }
```

this error usually raise when the cassandra table updated recently!
I don't know if this important, but there is another service connect to cassandra database and insert new data, is this related to problem? and how would I solve this error?

if the two services are the reason of this error, Are there any way to make cassandra table not blocked for (reading and writing) when there is active service write to cassandra table, mean no problem with ghost reading?

stack error:

```
{ [RangeError: index out of range]
  coordinator: '192.168.0.253:9042',
  query: 'SELECT * FROM table where hidden=false ALLOW FILTERING' }
RangeError: index out of range
    at checkOffset (buffer.js:663:11)
    at Buffer.readInt32BE (buffer.js:828:5)
    at Function.Long.fromBuffer (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/types/index.js:466:25)
    at Encoder.decodeLong (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/encoder.js:133:17)
    at Encoder.decodeTimestamp (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/encoder.js:142:26)
    at Encoder.decode (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/encoder.js:1202:18)
    at Parser.parseRows (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:377:36)
    at Parser.parseResult (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:335:10)
    at Parser.parseBody (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:185:19)
    at Parser._transform (/home/l.alassadi/alarm-socket/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:137:10)
```

Comment: Not sure what could have happened there.  Can you print the stack of the error (console.log(err.stack)).  Also which version of the nodejs driver are you using and what is the version of your C* cluster?

Comment: @AndyTolbert I've printed the error stack and edited the question.
cassandra version:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4]
Node js version:
v5.9.1 
cassandra-driver version: 3.2.0
but I don't understand what you mean by c* cluster version?

Comment: It looks like a driver bug... Can you reproduce it on a dev environment? Could you post the table schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR** fixed in `cassandra-driver` v3.6.0

---

`RangeError` is caused by a problem in `cassandra-driver`, specifically in how it decodes the data from db server. It appears in the following conditions:

1. The table contains a column with a `map` type
2. The map's value type is not nullable
3. The selected row has the said column
4. The value of the column (the map) has a key without a value (not quite sure how it's possible but it is)

Here are all nullable types:

- text
- ascii
- varchar
- custom
- blob

Long story short, the driver does not handle the case when a field of a not-nullable type (like int) inside a map is serialized as an empty buffer. In this case the driver is unconditionally trying to read from the buffer the amount of bytes equivalent to the type's size and fails with the said error.

Having this investigated, I've submitted a [fix](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/pull/294) to `cassandra-driver`. It has been accepted and released in 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error while doing a fetch from table. Since the error is at `Buffer.readInt32BE`, guessed that it's while parsing fields which could be of numeric type.

Looking at the stacktrace, went to the function `Function.Long.fromBuffer` and printed the `bytes` argument that gets passed. Now, looking at my query which had two fields of `Timestamp` type which can even be expressed as `Integer` type.

My query goes here `select item_id, created_date, modified_date from mytable`. Modified the library method to print the values which it encounters in `encoder.js`:

```
 this.decodeLong = function (bytes) {
    console.log("---->" + Long.fromBuffer(bytes));
    return Long.fromBuffer(bytes);
 };
```

Found that the first three values getting printed while executing my service method. Since it was the fourth item getting failed and my query had just two numeric types, concluded that the exception was during parsing of `modified_date` filed of second row.

Tried updating the `cassandra-driver`, the issue persisted. Deleted the row which was causing the issue and got this resolved. So, I guess, updating the field again to a different value should solve this. Looks like an inconsistency with the cassandra data.